# HTML5 Boilerplate and cirical rendering path / deffering scripts and styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, deferred-rendering

I used to build my websites based on the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/): styles and modenizr in the head, jQuery (google CDN or hosted file) and scripts before the closing body tag. Something like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <!-- modernizr conditional comments here -->
 <html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to remove all render-blocking below-the-fold css and js as [suggested by Googles PageSpeed Insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS).

How do I defer the css and js files including the jQuery library loaded from google?
What should I do about modernizr?

Answer (score 0):

To remove this particular warning you need to do the following:

- defer the load of all external CSS until after page onload
- defer the load of all external JS until after page onload

In practice that means you need to do the following:

- split your CSS into that required to avoid the "flash of unstyled content" (FOUC) and the rest
- split your javascript likewise
- inline the CSS and JS that is required
- defer the load of the other CSS and JS until after page onload.

Using build tools is the only sane way of doing this.  You can do it with various [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) tools, or with the ant-based [H5BP Build Script](https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script).

The basic method of deferring loads is as follows:

```
(function () {
    // Load jQuery after page onload
    function loadJS() {
        var url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js";
        var n = document.createElement("script");
        n.src = url;
        n.onload = loadJS1;
        document.body.appendChild(n);
    }

    // Load some JS after jquery has been loaded.
    function loadJS1() {
        var url = "js/main.js";
        var n = document.createElement("script");
        n.src = url;
        // Continue chaining loads if needed.
        //n.onload = loadJS2;
        document.body.appendChild(n);
    }

    // Check for browser support of event handling capability
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("load", loadJS, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent("onload", loadJS);
    } else {
        window.onload = loadJS;
    }
})();
```